# Querying a string for an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, markdown

I have an ajax request that `POST`s text to another PHP page, which renders it to markdown and sends it back. An example looks like this:

```
"<p>Meep, meep, <em>meep!!!</em></p>
<pre><code class="language-javascript">var foo = "bar";</code></pre>"
```

Now, if I wanted to find all elements with the selector `pre code`, how would I do that? I tried `$(text).find("pre code")` but with no results given back. What is the problem and how is it done right?

Comment: Did you try `$(text).find("pre > code")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) like this

`$('<output>').append($.parseHTML(str)).find('pre code')`

```js
var str = '<p>Meep, meep, <em>meep!!!</em></p>\
<pre><code class="language-javascript">var foo = "bar"\
;</code></pre>';
alert($('<output>').append($.parseHTML(str)).find('pre code').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was `.filter()`.

The text used in the original question is represented as the root area for jQuery - so `.filter()` has to be used - it returns a list of all the filtered elements. On that, I had to use `.find()` and got the desired result.

I needed to run `hightlight.js` over the returned output, here is what it looks like:

```
$html = $(data);
$html.filter("pre").find("code").each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
```